# Do I need gulp or Grunt if I build a NodeJS application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, gulp

Assume I have Stylus + nib, Jade, Passport, Mongoose, some other modules that I connect together inside my NodeJS application.

Now having all pre-compilers as Node modules and working fine do I need gulp or Grunt to makes things any simpler if I work on a backend/frontend solution, not just a set of frontend pages?

In other words, how can gulp or Grunt be useful when work on a fullstack NodeJS web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it mostly depends on tasks that you want to do. Some common tasks for web applications

- watch for file changes and restart application
- run tests everytime something changes
- reload the website in your browser when working on frontend
- deploy online
- create a package, and update npm repository/github or generally prepare a zip to be ready to deploy
- have task manager delete files that you don't need, *if you use bower this will help a lot*
- create images/sprites
- prepare frontend javascript/css *minify,concat,make use of cdn urls*

i use gulp for over 2 months it has made development experience pain free with automation.